# Value error Tensor must be the same graph as tensor, but dimensions seem to be fine

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to write a CNN in python using tensorflow 1.13.1. For some reason, even after simplifying my model to only a single affine layer I am getting a dimensions error. Here is the relevant code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, X_SHAPE[1], X_SHAPE[2], 1]) # X_SHAPE is the shape of the input image types I am workig with
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def my_model(X, y, is_training):
    output = X
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, output.shape[1] * output.shape[2] * 
    output.shape[3]])
    output = tf.layers.dense(output, 2) # makes the error
    output = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(output) 
    return output

y_out = my_model(X, y, is_training)
total_loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(tf.one_hot(y, 2), logits=y_out)
mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(total_loss)
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-3)

# batch normalization in tensorflow requires this extra dependency
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(mean_loss)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print('Training')
run_model(sess,y_out,mean_loss,X_train,y_train,8,64,100,train_step,True)
print('Validation')
run_model(sess,y_out,mean_loss,X_val,y_val,1,64)
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/t8484200/Documents/fanta/dicom_snippet.py", line 189, in <module>
    y_out = my_model(X, y, is_training)
  File "C:/Users/t8484200/Documents/fanta/dicom_snippet.py", line 181, in my_model
    output = tf.layers.dense(output, 2)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\core.py", line 188, in dense
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1227, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 530, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 554, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 975, in call
    outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 5629, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 350, in _apply_op_helper
    g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5713, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)
  File "C:\Users\t8484200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5649, in _assert_same_graph
    original_item))
ValueError: Tensor("dense/kernel:0", shape=(262144, 2), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, 262144), dtype=float32).
```

But dimensions seem to be fine, so I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a dimension error. The dimensions are just mentioned as part of the information about the two relevant tensors. I ran this code with tf 1.13.1 and it works for me.

I was able to get the same error for example when I replace the first 4 lines with: (same lines in different order)

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, X_SHAPE[1], X_SHAPE[2], 1]) # X_SHAPE is the shape of the input image types I am workig with
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

The reason is that X is created in the existing graph, and then a new graph is created by the reset command. Then the dense tensor is created in the new graph, but using X from the old graph which is not allowed. (It looks like the reshape command is in the old graph, maybe because it does not create new variables.)

So you need to check where you are resetting the graph compared to where you are defining your placeholders.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful, I didn't know enough about tensorflow graphs :)